# Question 9(b) Section- Fields and Galois Theory Sub section- Fundamental theorem of Galois Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, galois-extensions

I am trying some problems from Hungerford Algebra in Galois Theory.

I have a question in problem 9 whose image I am adding( I have also added statement of problem 6 in case it's useful) :

I have proved (a).

But problem arises in (b) .

I took $|K|= n  => Aut_K{ K(u) }\leq n^4$.

And $ |{1_K}':{Aut_{K}{K(x) }}'| \leq | Aut_{K} K(x) : 1_K| $

Now,as K(x) is Galois over K it implies $|K(x):K|\leq | Aut_{K} K(x)|\leq n^4$ .

But I am not able to see any contradiction.

Can you please tell how to get a contradiction in (b).

[image]

Comment: Show that the field extension $K\subset K(x)$ is not finite. (Clear or ambiguous?)

Comment: @user26857 Ok ,How to do that ? Any hints?

Comment: Find an infinite set which is linearly independent over K.